# PHP script on Amazon EC2 giving response 324 on browser

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have a script which downloads acsv file. When we run this script on command line on EC2 console it runs fine; downloads the file and sends success message to the user.

But if we run through a browser then we get:

> error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.

When we checked in backed for the file download, it's there but the success message  sent after the download is not received by the browser.

We are using cURL to download from a remote location with authentication. The user group and ownership of the folder is "ec2-user", the folder has full rights ie 777.

To summarize: the file is downloaded but at the browser end we are not getting any data or success message which we print.

P.S.: The problem occurs when the downloaded file size is 8-9MB; if it is a smaller file size say 1MB it works. So Either script executing time or download file size or some ec2 instance config is blocking it from giving browser a response. The same script is working perfectly fine on our Godaddy Linux VPS. We have already changed Max execution time for the script.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this is a known problem without a good solution. There's a very long thread on the amazon forum here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=33427. The solution offered there is to send a keep-alive message to keep the connection from dying after 60 seconds. Not a great solution, but I don't think there's a better one unless Amazon fixes the problem, which doesn't seem likely given that the thread has been open for 3 years.

Comment: Adam that is correct. We almost spend 4 days of this finally we broke down the file in smaller chunks.